# High Level Configuration of Constructor Injection in C++

Tags: c++, testing, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

My questions are specifically dealing with dependency injection through the constructor. I understand the pros/cons of service locator pattern, constructor/setter injection, and their flavors, however there is something I can't seem to get past after choosing pure constructor injection. After reading many materials for testable design, including a thorough perusing of Miško Hevery's blog (specifically [this](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/03/30/collaborator-vs-the-factory/) post) I'm at the following situation:

Assume I'm writing a C++ program, and I have correctly injected my dependencies through their constructors. For readability I have given myself a high-level object which has a single Execute() function called from main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MyAwesomeProgramObject object(argc, argv);
    return object.Execute();
}
```

Execute()'s responsibility is to simply wire up all required objects and kick off the highest level object. The highest level object requires a couple dependencies and those objects required a few objects and so on and so on, implying a function that looks like this:

```
MyAwesomeProgramObject::Execute() {
    DependencyOne one;
    DependencyTwo two;
    DependencyThree three;

    MidLevelOne mid_one(one);
    MidLevelTwo mid_two(two, three);

    // ...

    MidLevelN mid_n(mid_dependencyI, mid_dependencyJ, mid_dependencyK);

    // ...

    HighLevelObject1 high_one(mid_one, mid_n);
    HighLevelObject2 high_two(mid_two);

    ProgramObject object(high_one, high_two);
    return object.Go();
}
```

From what I take from Miško's blog (and I would ask him, but figured he wouldn't have time to get back to me), this is the only way to satisfy pure constructor injection of dependencies.

In the blog post [mentioned](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/03/30/collaborator-vs-the-factory/), he states we should have factories on a per object lifetime level, but this is essentially what Execute is doing, making my code look identical to his example:

```
AuditRecord audit = new AuditRecord();
Database database = new Database(audit);
Captcha captcha = new Captcha();
Authenticator authenticator =
    new Authenticator(database, captcha, audit);
LoginPage = new LoginPage(audit, authenticator);
```

### Questions:

- Is this the correct approach?
- Is this a pattern that I'm not aware of (seems similar to Maven's context.xml)?
- For pure constructor injection, do I simply suffer the cost of "upfront" allocation?

Comment: Is your `MyAwesomeProgramObject` just factory for `ProgramObject`? Your example is not identical because you have local variable of type `ProgramObject`. That is the big difference, the lifetime of your objects and this objects in example. E.g. LoginPage is alive until user logged - your `ProgramObject` is just a local variable for `MyAwesomeProgramObject::Execute()`...

Answer (score 0):

Note that your different examples are contradictory. At first you show creating objects on the stack, and your last example allocates objects.

Objects on the stack are somewhat dangerous, but just fine in most cases. The main problem is to give another object that has a longer lifetime than your function an object pointer when that object comes from the stack... when that long lived object tries to access the object on the stack after the function returned, you have a problem. If all the objects have a stack lifetime, then you're fine.

Personally, I started using shared pointers and I find that to be the ultimate in easing the management of a large number of objects.

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_object(new foo);
std::shared_ptr<blah> foo_object(new blah(foo));
```

In this way blah can hold a copy of the foo shared pointer forever and everything works as expected, even between function boundaries. Not only that, the shared pointer is NULL on creation, and auto-deleted on deletion (when the last shared pointer is deleted, of course.) And you can use weak pointer in objects that do not need the pointer to always be set...

Otherwise, I think that what you are trying to do works to a certain extend. In my world, it is often that things get created at a later time so I need a setter. However, constructor injections are very useful to force the user to properly initialize your object (i.e. I often create read-only objects, no setters, which are 100% initialized on construction, very practical, very safe!)